# Android not registering first click in fullscreen mode

Tags: java, android

I want to build an app that shows a looped fullscreen video when launched. As soon as the screen is touched the app will move on to the next Activity.
Only that when I tap the screen the first tap is not registered, but it rather shows the system bars again, and it changes activity on the second touch.

I´ve tried using Immersive mode, sticky Immersive mode, and fullscreen mode.
Here are the flags I used for entering immersive mode:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

    int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    getWindow().addFlags(flags);
```

Why is the first click not registered?